# Birthday email, blank rows, and wrong dates

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timezone, google-workspace

I have a google sheet with a list of names, email addresses and birthday. The contents looks something like this:

```
--------------------------------------------
| Name      | email        | Birthday      |
--------------------------------------------
| John Doe  | john@doe.com | 2018-05-13    |
| Jane Doe  | jane@doe.com | 2018-05-12    |
```

The date in the birthday column is being validated by google sheet as a date and I've used the datepicker to input those dates.

What I'd like to do next is to send an email on the appropriate birthday to the person but I've ran into a few problems. 
Here is the code, and I'll explain the problems after:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
var numRows = 1000;   // Number of rows to process
// Fetch the range of cells B2:B1000
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 1000)
// Fetch values for each row in the Range.
var data = dataRange.getValues();

function sendBirthdayEmails() {
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var startday = Utilities.formatDate(row[2], "UTC+2", "MM-dd"); //Store birthday without year
    var today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "UTC+2", "MM-dd"); //Store current date and remove year
    if (today == startday) { //Evaluate if today is a birthday
      var emailAddress = row[1]; // gather the email address
      var message = "Woop woop, " + row[0] + "!<br>Today is your " + (Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "UTC+1", "yyyy") - Utilities.formatDate(row[2], "UTC+1", "yyyy")) + " year(s) birthday!"; // Create the email message
      var subject = "Your birthday!"; //Set email subject
      //MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {htmlBody: message, replyTo: "birthday@example.com", name: "Birthday wishes", bcc: "myself@exmaple.com"}); //Invoke sending the email
    }
  }
}
```

I am sure there are many more smooth ways of handling these things, and if there is, let me know. I am however running into two issues mainly:
1. For reasons I cannot explain, the date from the birthday column evaluates to the previous day at 22:00. This sounds like a timezone issue since I am currently in UTC+2 (CEST). But how do I tackle it?
2. The script is having issues with empty rows/cells and throws errors when processing them, what is the correct way of handling this? I assume that what I am doing above when fetching rows 2 to 1000 can be done in a better way?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that...
Spreadsheet settings:
Locale: Sweden
Timezone: GMT+1 (Stockholm)

Comment: You didn't answer all of @pnuts qs.

Comment: Timezone in script project is GMT+1 (Paris). Changed it to Stockholm (even tho it shouldnt matter) with the same results.

Comment: Need more information. What does Logs say the date was? Screenshot of the logs....  Possible dirty Workarounds: use getDisplayValues() instead of getValues(). This will return the exact string in the cell instead of a date object. Use the string to initialise a new date object,if need be. Also use `sheet.getLastRow` instead of a arbitrary 1000 numRows

Comment: Thanks! I changed it to used sheet.getLastRow (and column) but I am still seeing issues when it processes the last row, which is considered empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look at your data and replicated the error:

I have a cell that contains "2018-05-13". The column is formatted as a Date and the data validation is set to Date. The Spreadsheet settings say the timezone is GMT and the script properties say the timezone is GMT.

```
var value = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell();
Utilities.formatDate(value, "GMT", "MM-dd);
```

This returns "05-12" which is wrong by 1 day.

A lot of digging around suggests this [solution](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/docs/SvH9CDYr1ZI/Jh019NBfYGQJ):

```
Utilities.formatDate(value, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM-dd");
```

Which returns the correct value.

`Session.getScriptTimeZone()` returns the value "Europe/London" for me, which must take into account daylight saving time and causes Utilities.formatDate to behave differently.

Comment: Great! Thank you, that really helped! :)
Now I just need to stop processing when there is a row without any data in it :)

Comment: Did the following validation on first cell of each row and that seems to work:
    if (row[0] == "") {
      Logger.log("Breaking out")
      break;
    }